# How to format the decimal values in the form of e/E

Tags: java

I want to format a decimal value in a form that's something like 1.123e-4 while the actual value is 0.0001123

Comment: Hello. what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably this what you are looking at to display **decimal values in Exponential form**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double a = 0.0001123;
        String value = String.valueOf(a.doubleValue());
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

**output**

```
1.123E-4
```

Comment: @Sourabh pls accept the answer if it works for you, it will help others as well

Comment: Yeah, this works for `0.0001123` but what about for other values?

Comment: `Double a = 0.1123;`  Output is the same `0.1123`

Comment: @ScaryWombat i got the same question being answered on stackoverflow, so marked closed, tried deleting the answer, but could not. Thanks